# How to compare the value in the same day in r?

Tags: r, datatable

I want to compare the signal within the same day, and try to use for loop to handle this problem, but I think there should have more efficient function to solve this problem.

The given dataset:

| Signal | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2000-01-01 |
| 2 | 2000-01-01 |
| 2 | 2000-01-01 |
| 2 | 2000-01-02 |
| 5 | 2000-01-02 |

My expected output:

| Signal | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 2000-01-01 |
| 5 | 2000-01-02 |

Comment: What do you mean by compare? Try to be more specific

Comment: I mean get the maximum value of signal in every date groups

Comment: You just said that you don't want the maximum value if it more than 10?

Comment: I type it wrong, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can infer from your comments that `Signal` is actually a character or factor vector which should be converted to numeric before attempting to order it - otherwise a signal of "2" will be higher than a signal of "10" due to alphabetic ordering.

In any case, the example data you posted can be coerced on the fly if required, so the following code should work whatever the format is (numeric, character, or factor):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  slice_max(as.numeric(as.character(Signal)), with_ties = FALSE)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#> # Groups:   Date [2]
#>   Signal Date      
#>   <chr>  <chr>     
#> 1 2      2000-01-01
#> 2 5      2000-01-02
```

Or better still

```r
df %>%
  mutate(Signal = as.numeric(as.character(Signal))) %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  slice_max(Signal, with_ties = FALSE)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#> # Groups:   Date [2]
#>   Signal Date      
#>   <dbl>  <chr>     
#> 1 2      2000-01-01
#> 2 5      2000-01-02
```

---

**Data from question in reproducible format**

```r
df <- structure(list(Signal = c("1", "2", "2", "2", "5"), Date = c("2000-01-01", 
"2000-01-01", "2000-01-01", "2000-01-02", "2000-01-02")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```